Contextual awareness for Auto Completion using antlr4-c3 [SQL]
I am trying to write Auto-completion for SQL-Queries. I want to recommend contextual Tables.
The query might be: Select  from test with the caret being between select and from. I would like to only recommend fields from the given table. Is there a way to do this using antlr4-c3? I think i would have to skip the missing identification token to get to the table-identifier.

This might also be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37068536/implement-language-auto-completion-based-on-antlr4-grammar
